# save dataframe containing lists as csv file

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I have created DataFrame as the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': imgname, 'pose': pose})
```

where imgname is a list of string such as ['image1','image2' ...]
the pose is a list of list such as pose = [array([ 55.77614093,   8.45208199,   2.69841043,   2.17110961]),
array([ 66.61236215,   5.87653161, -31.70704038, -21.68979529])]

I use this line to write the Dataframe to csv file

```
df.to_csv('dataset.csv',index = 'False')
```

However, the pose col is converted to a string with '\n' and extra spaces

How can I save the values as numbers in csv format

Comment: Can you show me a printout of your dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

For `pose`, you probably do not mean `array`s as list of list.
Your code would work if you remove the `array` part -

```
import pandas as pd    
imgname = ['image1','image2'] 
pose = [[ 55.77614093, 8.45208199, 2.69841043, 2.17110961],[6.61236215, 5.87653161, -31.70704038, -21.68979529]]
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': imgname, 'pose': pose})
```

df output -

```
name    pose
0   image1  [55.77614093, 8.45208199, 2.69841043, 2.17110961]
1   image2  [66.61236215, 5.87653161, -31.70704038, -21.68...
```

after that,

```
df.to_csv('dataset.csv',index = 'False')
```

works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]), np.array([5,6,7,8])], 'IMAGE' : ['IMAGE1', 'IMAGE2']})
print (df)

df.to_csv('dataset.csv',index = 'False')
```

and the result is the following :
[image: csv file]